# sniff sql data over network

Tags: sql-server, debugging, sniffer

Is it possible to sniff ms-sql data that is transferred over the network?(assuming the connection is not encrypted?)

Trying to use Wireshark to sniff the data on the network, was a bit complex to extract the data , as there are many more layers of data covering the "interesting" staff, that could help debugging.

Comment: SQL Server uses the TDS protocol. AFAIK wireshark can decode these packets if that is the level you are interested in.

Comment: very useful to write in wireshare fileter " tds " thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to view the SQL Queries, Open SQL Server Management Studio and to go Tools -> SQL Profiler. Connect the profiler to your database and run some queries - you'll see the queries appear in the profiler. I don't think SQL Profiler lets you view the returned data.

If you're using N/Hibernate, EntityFramework, Linq2SQL or LLBgen then check out the Hibernating Rhinos Profilers at http://hibernatingrhinos.com/products

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the SQL Server Profiler? An invaluable tool for monitoring the activity over the network to and from the SQL Server?

Answer (score 1):

If you can arrange for `alter trace` permissions on the server, consider using [SQL Server Profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187929.aspx).  You can use a filter to limit the capture to a particular client.